# How to get count in output variable using a stored procedure?

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM tblRequest 
GROUP BY RequestStatusID
```

This query return the column having total requests respective status `Id`.

I want to get **total** requests count respective to its `statusId` in output variables using a stored procedure.

This query return the column having total requests respective status Id.

I want to get total requests respective to its statusId in a output variable using stored procedure.

i.e. it returns a column like

```
______________  
|NoNameColumn|  
|------------|  
|      21    |
|       6    |  
|      14    |
|------------|
```

I want to get each row value in a output variable separately (eg. SET @pending=21, Set @Sent=6, SET Discarded=14 ), using stored procedure and vb.net code.

In simple words: how can I get that row's values in a variable by the SQL Server stored procedure?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Stored procedures and procedural SQL is **highly** vendor-specific - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountRequests
@requests int output
AS
SELECT @requests = COUNT(*) FROM tblRequest GROUP BY RequestStatusID
```

or just select it

```
SELECT COUNT(*) requests FROM tblRequest GROUP BY RequestStatusID
```

Answer (score -2):

i used the following stored procedure to return the value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_count

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @VALUE int;

SET @VALUE=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblRequest GROUP BY RequestStatusID);

RETURN @VALUE;

END
GO
```

Comment: But it didnt return a single value. it return a Column

Comment: u want the count with respect to the status id..?? it will return the count of each status id

Comment: No i do not want to count for respective status Id. I want to count for each status ID. And I want get each count in separate output variable in store procedure.